# VS15 throws error C2975 with constexpr and a string literal

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, constexpr

I'm trying to implement a class that performs string hashing at compile-time if a literal string is given or else, run-time (based on [this article](http://altdevblog.com/2011/10/27/quasi-compile-time-string-hashing/)).
I'm not using FNV-1a like the author did but [xxHash](http://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash/) (64bits), for the compile-time calculation I'm using [this code](https://github.com/ekpyron/xxhashct).

Here's my implementation:

```
class StringHash {
public:
    class ConstCharWrapper {
    public:
        inline ConstCharWrapper( const char *Str ) : Internal(Str) {}
        const char *Internal;
    };

template <size_t N>
__forceinline StringHash( const char (&Str)[N] ) :
    m_Hash( std::integral_constant<uint64_t, xxh64::hash(Str, N-1)>::value )
{
}

inline StringHash( ConstCharWrapper Str ) :
    m_Hash( xxHash_64::Calc((const uint8_t*)Str.Internal, strlen(Str.Internal)) )
{
}

inline StringHash( const char *Str, size_t Length ) :
    m_Hash( xxHash_64::Calc((const uint8_t*)Str, Length) )
{
}

__forceinline operator uint64_t() const { return m_Hash; }

private:
    const uint64_t m_Hash;
};
```

Literal strings are properly dispatched to the template constructor but I noticed, by looking at the generated assembly, that the hashing was not completely calculated at compile-time.

So I used a `std::integral_constant` to force the compiler to do it a compile-time but now I'm getting a C2975 error (`'_Val' : invalid template argument for 'std::integral_constant', expected compile-time constant expression`).

When trying to figure out what the problem could be, I tried to put an hard-coded string directly into the template constructor:

```
template <size_t N>
__forceinline StringHash( const char (&Str)[N] ) :
    m_Hash( std::integral_constant<uint64_t, xxHash_CT::h64("foobar", 6)>::value )
{
}
```

And it worked just fine...
I have no clue what the problem could be, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, in here:

```
template <size_t N>
__forceinline StringHash( const char (&Str)[N] ) :
    m_Hash( std::integral_constant<uint64_t, xxh64::hash(Str, N-1)>::value )
//                                                      ^^^^^^
{
}
```

`Str` isn't a constant expression (because function parameters aren't constant expressions), so you can't use the result of `hash()` as a constant expression. In order to make this work, we'd need to be able to have string literal template parameters, which is a work in progress ([P0424](https://wg21.link/p0424)).

Your other example works because `"foobar"` *is* a constant expression.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Is there a workaround or another way to achieve a similar functionality ?

Comment: @Spacebrain Compile time string processing? You'd have to manually encode your types... `struct X { static constexpr const char* value = "hello"; };`